# previously displayed images disappear after mouse-click

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, jlabel

I'm programming a gui for a network-able battleships-like game (yes me too).
If I right-click to set a waypoint all the mapLabels disappear and I don't get it, since all the right-click should do is to send some string to the server and not in any way influence the display itself.
If I call panel.repaint(); pane.validate(); after setting a waypoint everything is displayed again, but performance is coming close to impossibly slow like that.

I realize, this is a lot of code, but I can't imagine the problem beeing in the FieldListener, though it must be. Therefore I have no idea what to post. If you want to see something else, you could ask for it...

Here's the part of our code, that most probably is responsible for the problem:

```
/**
 * The listener for a field.
 * @author Andris
 *
 */
private class FieldListener implements MouseListener {

    private int[] xy;
    private int[] pressedPos = new int[] {-1,-1};


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        Field field = map.getField(xy[0],xy[1]);
        pressedPos = xy.clone();
        switch(evt.getButton()){
        case MouseEvent.BUTTON1://-------well, BUTTON1......
            break;
        case MouseEvent.BUTTON3:
            switch(selBtn){
            case 2://---------------this is the case
                client.Out("some string");// this sends to the server, nothing else...
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

after the server answers this is executed (in totally different classes from different packages, and all the disappearing fields are private, though):

```
public class Server {
   client.Out(cfg.chat_server+"you have set a waypoint at ("+x+","+y+").");

public class ChatFrame extends JPanel {
    public void Out(String nextString){
        text.append(" "+nextString);
        text.append("\n");
        JScrollBar scroll = display.getVerticalScrollBar();
        if(!scroll.getValueIsAdjusting())scroll.setValue(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
```

Here's the custom paint method (maybe this as ImageObserver is wrong):

```
private class MapLabel extends JLabel{ //------------- in MapFrame

    private Field field;
    private int[] xy;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Image image = getImageNsetToolTip();
        Graphics2D g2D=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, actImgSize, actImgSize, this);
        g2D.setClip(0, 0, actImgSize, actImgSize);
        super.paint(g2D);
    }

    /**
     * gets the proper image and sets the tool-tip
     * @return
     */
    private Image getImageNsetToolTip(){
        Image result;
        String toolTip = "("+xy[0]+","+xy[1]+")";
        TileType type = field.getType();
        switch(type){
        case harbor:
            result=harborImg[0];
            break;
        case land: 
//------------------------------etc...


        this.setToolTipText(toolTip);
        return result;
    }
```

Here's some of the rest:

```
...lots of imports...

/**
 * This is the frame in which the GameMap is displayed.
 * @author Andris
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MapFrame extends JPanel {

...lots of variables...

    /**
     * Creates the frame, but doesn't make it visible yet.
     * @param window the GameWindow in which this frame will be embedded.
     * @param client the client who runs this.
     */
    public MapFrame(GameWindow window, Client client){

...lots of variables initialized...

        panel = new JPanel();
        pane = new JScrollPane(panel,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        buttons = new JButton[nButtons];
        buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        for(int i=0; i<nButtons; i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonTexts[i]);
            buttons[i].setName(buttonTexts[i].replace(' ', '_'));
            buttons[i].addActionListener(buttonListener);
            buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcom to SO. Unfortunately, it's unlikely someone will answer this because it contains too much code and it is incomplete; so it's pretty hard to help you. Show some effort and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), this will get you valuable help in no time.

Comment: Since I have no idea where the problem lies, and our code is some 3000+ lines I don't consider it to contain too much code and I couldn't recreate the problem in a smaller program...

Comment: _Since I have no idea where the problem lies, and our code is some 3000+ lines_ Hence the idea of the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If you follow the approach described in the link, it will highly improve the chances of finding the problem and obtain a smaller program that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:
There are quite a few threads running because the server, the client, each connection and what-not are running in their own threads.
This *can* cause the swing event-queue to act up, with the result, that things are not executed when they are supposed to.
This usually happens only, if there are *many* other threads (thus the impossibility to make a SSCCE).
In order to prevent this every method like validate() or repaint() should be invoked as invokeLater (and therefore be handled by the event-queue properly), especially if they are called from a different thread.
So this is what I wrote everywhere:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @override
        public void run(){
            panel.validate();
            panel.repaint();
            pane.validate();
        }
    });
```

or:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @override
        public void run(){
            mapLabels[x][y].repaint();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem, with your paint code

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Image image = getImageNsetToolTip();
    Graphics2D g2D=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, actImgSize, actImgSize, this);
    g2D.setClip(0, 0, actImgSize, actImgSize);
    super.paint(g2D);
 }
```

Painting before `super.paint` can have the potential of wiping out what you have previously painted. This occurs because `paint` calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintComponents`.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the graphics context for painting (cleaning it up)

You should, also, avoid messing with the clip. Because of the way painting works in Swing, you run the risk of allowing the component to paint beyond its physical boundaries.  The clip is set by the repaint manager to equal the size of the component before `paint` is called

Instead, you should be using `paintComponent` to perform your custom painting

Take a look at [Perofming custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Now, the question that raises to my mind, why are you painting a custom image on a `JLabel`, when one of the features of a `JLabel` is to display a icon?

Comment: I am trying to improve performance. Someone told me to rather rewrite the paint or paintCompnent method than to use ImageIcons (allegedly more effecient rescaling) though I didn't find it (noticeably) more efficient.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but they didn't solve the main problem (though leaving out setClip seems to have no negative effect and therefore certainly is an improvement). Now that you mentioned it I realized, that I probably should have stuck to my (own and) old plan of using ImageIcons and give up improving performance. Thanks

Comment: Hence the last statement ;)